# Site navigation : setting a ribbon/header constant

Tags: html, css, web, navigation

I believe this is a `HTML/CSS` question - how you set a header or ribbon constant. As in, just have the body change. For example the facebook website. When you click on `Profile`, the body of the page changes, but that bar stays the same. Same when you click `Home`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the FB code but in essence, to answer your generic question, they are two different pages with the same code for the toolbar.

On one side you have the web page page layout and design, on the other you code it: say PHP, ASP, etc with using a template engine. 
This way you can place the code for toolbar, content, footer, etc and later merge it on you way, producing "similar" paging reusing the same parts.
The PHP, ASP, etc code is responsible to "decide" which menu, option, ... must be highlighted to indicate the section you are.

Other way is the AJAX way, like google gmail, where the content of the page changes dinamically requesting new content via AJAX and not reloading the page.